# Unity, resources.loadall() returns null objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the image used for a sprite in unity, I am getting the error:NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
This has led me to believe that my loadall function is not working since it returns an array of null objects. Here is my code:

```
Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprite/Chests");
```

I then use the array with this line:

```
SpriteRender.sprite = sprites[SpriteIndex];
```

Comment: what is `SpriteRender`? can you add the line where you are creating this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: SpriteRender is the game component SpriteRenderer, as per line SpriteRender = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

Answer (score 0):

in the function `Resources.LoadAll` the path parameter is the path from `Resources` folder so  `Sprite/Chests` must be under `Resources` folder. so your folder structure must be like this  `Resources -> Sprite -> Chests`

Answer (score -1):

Try doing:

```
Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll("Sprite/Chests", typeof(Sprite));
```

Otherwise you most likely have a path issue and you need to change your "Sprite/Chests" into the proper path.

Comment: Your codeline and `Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Sprite/Chests");` as used by the OP are doing exactly the same thing. They just use different (old) overloads of the same method. So your answer doesn't add any additional information.